# Guarding for composed union type | TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a function that accepts either an array of various objects or mouse point:

```
function zoomTo(target : Array<Cube|Circle> | createjs.Point)
```

But when I try to guard for the type, no matter what way, I get an error:

```
if (target instanceof Array<Cube|Circle>) 

if (typeof target === Array<Cube|Circle>)
```

> Error:(142, 46) TS1005: '(' expected.

Am I doing something wrong or is the composed union type too much for TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`instanceof` an only be used with Classes which are Javascript classes (i.e. without any generics).

If you use it on the [Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground), you see the following error:

> The right-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of type 'any' or of a type assignable to the 'Function' interface type.

[Example with error](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20Cube%20%7B%20%7D%0Aclass%20Circle%20%7B%20%7D%0Aclass%20Point%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0Afunction%20zoomTo(target%3A%20Array%3CCube%7CCircle%3E%20%7C%20Point)%20%7B%0A%09if%20(target%20instanceof%20Point)%20%7B%0A%09%09%0A%09%7D%20else%20if%20(target%20instanceof%20Array%3CCube%7CCircle%3E)%20%7B%0A%09%09%0A%09%7D%0A%7D).

Hence, you can write `target instanceof Array`, but not `target instanceof Array<number>`.

---

In your case, I would resolve the problem by checking whether `target` is an instance of `createjs.Point` instead:

```
if (target instanceof createjs.Point) {
   // ...
} else {
   // target instanceof Array == true
   // ...
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this is failing in my WebStorm editor.

Comment: disregard my comment please. WebStorm has it's proprietary TypeScript compiler and it is failing to validate the expression even if it works in the MS playground.